# jquery - show / hide div depending on day and time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show a specific div depending on the day and time.

So if the Day is between Monday - Friday and the Time is between 9am - 5:30pm,

then it will show div = class.open

if before or after that time, it will show div = class.closed

I have the following code that works to show the .open div when open, Monday-Friday 9am to 5pm. And it will show the .closed div from 0am to 9am. But I need it to show the closed div anytime it is outside of Monday-Friday 9am-5pm.

So I have 2 questions:

1. How do I have the .closed div show whenever it is not Monday-Friday 9am to 5pm?
2. How can I add minutes in, like open 8:30am to 5:30pm?

**CODE**

```
<div class="hours">We are OPEN</div>
<div class="closed">We are CLOSED</div>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var d = new Date();
    var dayOfWeek = d.getDay();
    var hour = d.getHours();

    // open hours Monday - Friday 9am - 5:pm = open
    if (dayOfWeek === 6 || dayOfWeek === 0 || hour <= 9 || hour >= 17) {
        $('.hours').hide();
    }
    // closed any other time than above * working from 0am -9am but none other
    if (dayOfWeek === 6 || dayOfWeek === 0 || hour <= 0 || hour >= 9) {
        $('.closed').hide();
    }


});
```

Here is the example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wft0sjz8/)

Comment: If you have two mutually exclusive conditions and one or the other is always true, this is a prime use case for an if/else statement rather than two ifs

Comment: @dwreck08 honestly, if this was the most ridiculous request you have from client in a whole year, then it's a good year.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compare the [`getTime()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp)'s of the dates specified.

The below code sets Opening Time and Closing Time of the current day and checks whether the current time is between those two time stamps.

```js
var Now = new Date(),
  CurrentDay = Now.getDay(),
  OpeningTime = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), 8, 30),
  ClosingTime = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), 17, 30),
  Open = (Now.getTime() > OpeningTime.getTime() && Now.getTime() < ClosingTime.getTime());

if (CurrentDay !== 6 && CurrentDay !== 0 && Open) {
    $('.openstatus').toggle();
}
```

```css
.hours {
  display:none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hours openstatus">We are OPEN</div>
<div class="closed openstatus">We are CLOSED</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to define timezone? It doesn't appear to be working

Comment: @JozefPietrzak For timezones you'll need to use something like [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (dayOfWeek !== 6 && dayOfWeek !== 0 && hour >= 9 && hour < 17) {
    $('.hours').show();
    $('.closed').hide();
}
else {
    $('.hours').hide();
    $('.closed').show();
}
```

Consider using moment.js, IDs instead of classes and a timed refresh.

Comment: thanks @Lucas. Do you know how to add minutes? I tried adding hour <17 && mins <= 30, but it did not work.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning see my answer for a much cleaner method of comparing times

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all that helped. @gibberish, great answer thanks.
@Jamie, thanks for the detailed info and script rewrite. works perfect.

I added the below so that it may help someone in the future looking for this answer and why it works/ how to modify it.

**CODE**

```js
var Now = new Date();
var CurrentDay = Now.getDay();
// opening time - 24 hours so 9:30am is 9, 30
var OpeningTime = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), 11, 36);
// closing time - 24 hours so 5:30pm is 17, 30
var ClosingTime = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), 17, 30);
var Open = (Now.getTime() > OpeningTime.getTime() && Now.getTime() < ClosingTime.getTime())
// days 0.sun 1.mon 2.tues 3.wed 4.thur 5.fri 6.sat 
// CurrentDay !== 0 && the # is the day to eclude, so if I want to be closed on Sat6, Sun0, Wed3
// CurrentDay !== 6 && CurrentDay !== 0 && CurrentDay !== 3 && Open
if (CurrentDay !== 0 && CurrentDay !== 6 && Open) {
    $('.openstatus').toggle();
}
```

```css
.hours {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="hours openstatus">We are OPEN</div>
<div class="closed openstatus">We are CLOSED</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Lucas' answer, this is a simple addition to allow for minutes:

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wft0sjz8/1/)

```
var d = new Date();
var dayOfWeek = d.getDay();
var hour = d.getHours();
var mins = d.getMinutes();
var status = 'open';

if (dayOfWeek !== 6 && dayOfWeek !== 0 && hour >= 9 && hour <= 17){
    if (hour=='9' && mins < '30'){
        status = 'closed';
    }else if (hour=='17' && mins > '30'){
        status = 'closed';
    }else{
        status = 'open';
    }
}else{
    status = 'closed';
}

if (status=='open') {
    $('.hours').show();
    $('.closed').hide();
}else{
    $('.hours').hide();
    $('.closed').show();
}
```

Comment: It'll work, but it's clunky. Also FYI it'll never hit the second `else if hour=='17'` because your opening statement is checking for it being < 17

Comment: Thanks for catching that, Jamie -- too many interruptions over here. Only thought to include this example because the OP looks like he might understand it better. I remember only too well being in his shoes a year or so ago myself.