# Show / hide div depending on day and time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show a specific div depending on the day and time.

During the hours of 8am - 7pm Monday to Friday and 8:30am - 4pm on Saturdays, an div with a "we are open" message is to show. Outside of these hours, a closed message div will show.

I have seen other posts ( [jquery - show / hide div depending on day and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835495/jquery-show-hide-div-depending-on-day-and-time) ) which achieve this for one day but not for two different day groups and different sets of opening hours and I have not been able to work out how to get it to work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you tried anything after looking at the post you've mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<script>
function ShowOnTime(element){

    var daysWorking = [{dayWorking: 1, startTimeWorking: '8', endTimeWorking: '19'}, {dayWorking: 2, startTimeWorking: '8', endTimeWorking: '19'}, {dayWorking: 3, startTimeWorking: '8', endTimeWorking: '19'}, {dayWorking: 4, startTimeWorking: '8', endTimeWorking: '19'}, {dayWorking: 5, startTimeWorking: '8', endTimeWorking: '19'}, {dayWorking: 6, startTimeWorking: '830', endTimeWorking: '16'}];
    var a = new Date(); 
    var nowDay = a.getDay(); //0-6 denotes Sunday, monday, tuesday etc etc.
    var nowHours = a.getHours();
    var nowMinutes = a.getMinutes();

    if(daysWorking.find(o => o.dayWorking === nowDay)){
        if (daysWorking.find(o => o.startTimeWorking <= (nowHours+''+nowMinutes)) && daysWorking.find(o => o.endTimeWorking >= (nowHours+''+nowMinutes))) {
            $(element).show();
        } else {
            $(element).hide();
        }
    } else {
        $(element).hide();
    }

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    ShowOnTime("#TestDiv"); 
});
</script>
```

Hope, this will get you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one more condition for Saturday in that answer

```js
var Now = new Date('11/4/2019 10:11:00');
 var CurrentDay = Now.getDay();
 if (CurrentDay!=6)
 {
      var OpenHour=8;
      var OpenMin=0;
      var CloseHour=19;
      var CloseMin=0;
 }
 else
 {
 var OpenHour=8;
      var OpenMin=30;
      var CloseHour=16;
      var CloseMin=0;
 }
var  OpeningTime = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), OpenHour, OpenMin);
var  ClosingTime = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), CloseHour, CloseMin);
var  Open = (Now.getTime() > OpeningTime.getTime() && Now.getTime() < ClosingTime.getTime());
if (CurrentDay !== 0 && Open) {
        $('.openstatus').toggle();
    }
```

```css
.hours {
      display:none;  
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="hours openstatus">We are OPEN</div>
    <div class="closed openstatus">We are CLOSED</div>
```